# Android app crashes when write Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to write some data into SQLite database.
In my application I have a main singleton class with code:

```
public class Singleton extends Application {

    public static DBHelper dbHelper;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }
}
```

DBHelper.java:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE AlarmListTable ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "time text, "
            + "date text, "
            + "comment text "
            + ");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

I have an activity in which I have a method:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("time", entTime.getText().toString());
cv.put("date", entTime.getText().toString());
cv.put("comment", entTime.getText().toString());
Singleton.db.insert("AlarmListTable", null, cv);
```

But application crashes.
Help me please. What is wrong with it?

**logcat:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException at Singleton.db.insert("AlarmListTable", null, cv);
```

Comment: did you use a debugger?

Comment: Possibly because you have an extra `,` after the last column in your `CREATE TABLE` script?

Comment: Please provide a crash log.

Comment: do you have write permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Singleton.db` is null.

Are you sure `onCreate()` in `Singleton` is being called? For `Application` subclasses, you need to add your subclass's name in the `android:name` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is solution!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is probably because you forgot to remove a coma at the end of your string. Also add a space after each of your comas.

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE AlarmListTable ("
                + "id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "time text, "
                + "date text, "
                + "comment text "
                + ");");
```

You'll have to add more details on your actual error to know for sure where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted coma, but it still crashes. Problem with insert.